# Using Parent 403 Error for Sub Application in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, http-status-code-403

I have an asp.net website
Inside this, I have an application and a folder called "Sites" which is filled with more applications.

```
Website
    /Application
    /Sites
         /Application 1
         /Application 2
         etc...
```

I would like any 403 errors anywhere inside the Website to show Application/Error/NotAuthorised, while keeping the URL in the address bar the same, which is why I have used ExecuteURL

So far I have in the Website config

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <error statusCode="403" subStatusCode="14" path="/Application/Error/NotAuthorised" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

Which correctly redirects from any 403 error in Website/Application, and the 403 when browsing to Website/Sites/

However, when browsing to Websites/Sites/Application 1, I get a 403, but it is just a completely blank page.

I believe this is due to the fact that Application 1 is also a application, so instead of looking for Website/Application/Error/NotAuthorised, it looks for the error page inside the currently executing application, which would make it Website/Sites/Application 1/Application/Error/NotAuthorised, which obviously doesn't exist.

Is there a way I can get IIS to always use Website/Application/Error/NotAuthorised, regardless of which application is running (assuming still inside Website)?

Comment: Do you have web.config files for each of your applications (Application 1, Application 2)? If not add a web.config with custom error section pointing to the URL you want.

Comment: I do not have control over those webconfig files, since they are uploaded by users for use in their own application.

Comment: Users are rejected as not authorised by checking a custom role provider provided by Application, so I was hoping that since they are bounced "out" of the Site, the Application would take over the error handling

Comment: But, you must have a look at those child web.config files to see whether they override the CustomError setting. If they does whatever you configure in the parent level will be overridden. Otherwise the parent config setting is sufficient.

Comment: And, I just notice that Application is not the parent of Application 1 and Application 2. It is sites. So, if you have a web.config with custom error settings under application it won't apply to Application 1 and Application 2. You should have this web.config under "Sites" or have it under "Website"